# 100vh in Google Search Console

Tags: responsive-design, google-search-console

I've a big problem. Google Search Console doesn't correctly fetch my website. The website consist of five sections with parameters:

```
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
min-height: 100%;
```

Google bot renders only first section, what about the others?

Answer (score 1):

Add a `max-height` to `1080px` for the element which has `height: 100vh` and leave `min-height` blank.

For example:

```
.element {
    height: 100vh;
    max-height: 1080px;
}
```

For us, this solved the issue within Google Search Console Visual renderer.